# Why my Phone authentication security rules not working?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I"m using firestore and my security rules not working! I wanted to access the database based on the user logged in, my structure looks like this, user/userid/user's collections.
logged-in users are only allowed to access their own data /userId/their own data.

My security rule:

```
   rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
     match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /user/{userId}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
         match /{subCollections=**} {
                allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** This same & code structure works fine with Email and password authentication but not working with phone Auth.

Comment: Try setting the rule to `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`. If it still fails then you are probably not logged in.

Comment: request.auth != null does work but this is not safe. as I wanted to compare the requested auth with the user id (doc).

Comment: What "isn't working"?

Comment: request.auth.uid == userId <--- this is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! as I have contacted firebase support, they told me that the error I'm getting on the simulation is because ID is not being matched with the requested id this is obvious. So my mistake was that I'm using a wildcard on the path area like user/{userId} instead of user/randomId324234.... and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

- `request.auth.token.sub` is for the realtime database
- `request.auth.uid` is for Firestore

Ensure you are using the correct information and parameters per your database and that the user is logged in successfully before accessing data requests.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#leverage_user_information_in_rules

Comment: Yes, I have also done that using request.auth.uid. but not working and I followed the docs you mentioned but still, the problem remains.

Comment: can you produce a minimal project for users to recreate the issue? without being able to recreate it locally, we can't find out what is wrong. I would otherwise suggest contacting firebase support but they will want a minimal project as well, but they will not compile projects from source.